# Flutter gridview fill remaining height on screen

Tags: flutter, dart

For the life of me I am not able to get the *gridview.count* to use the available height.
I have tried with the *MediaQuery.of(context).size.height* and *width* and tried with *SafeArea* but no luck.

Everything is contained in a Column.
The black bar is a *container* with a set height of 150 pixels. The grayblue bar is also a *container* with a set height of 50 pixels.

[image: calc]

[image]

code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            DefaultTextStyle(
              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 40.0),
              child: Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 120.0,
                child: FittedBox(
                  fit: BoxFit.contain,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(results),
                  ),
                ),
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
            DefaultTextStyle(
              style: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white54,
                fontSize: 5.0,
              ),
              child: Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 50.0,
                child: FittedBox(
                  fit: BoxFit.contain,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(history),
                  ),
                ),
                color: Colors.blueGrey,
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: GridView.count(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                crossAxisCount: 4,
                mainAxisSpacing: 2.0,
                crossAxisSpacing: 2.0,
                children: List.generate(
                  chars.length,
                  (index) {
                    return Material(
                      color: Colors.blueAccent,
                      child: InkWell(
                        // splashColor: Colors.amber,
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            
                          });
                        },
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(chars[index]),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can you include code instead of code-image?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I have added the code

Comment: This layout might be more suited to [`Table`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Table-class.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GridView` children size depends on screen size.

Child size `screenWidth/crossAxisCount` and the default aspect ratio is 1 that's why default view is square.  I will prefer calculating height for `GridView` then provide available height on top two containers.

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.purpleAccent,
    body: LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        const crossAxisCount = 4;

        final gridViewHeight =
            (constraints.maxWidth / crossAxisCount) * 5; //5 for rows

        final double heightWithoutGridView =
            constraints.maxHeight - gridViewHeight;

        return Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              width: constraints.maxWidth,
              height: heightWithoutGridView * .75,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            Container(
              width: constraints.maxWidth,
              height: heightWithoutGridView * .25,
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: GridView.count(
                crossAxisCount: crossAxisCount,
                children: List.generate(
                  44,
                  (index) => Container(
                    color: Colors.amber,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        );
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: This works for me many thanks. Do you also know how to approach this with the Expanded widget?

Comment: in that case, you can use `Column` , `Row` and `Flexiable` widgets

Comment: Love this - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Expanded widget provided by flutter. So, wrap your gridview with Expanded. Expanded will take all the available space of the screen.

Comment: The thing is it's already wrapped in Expanded widget but it does not take the remaining space. I added the another picture showing it.

Comment: Okay, I now see it.